# What does a Java static method look like in Ruby?

Tags: java, ruby

In Java, a 'static method' would look like this:

```
class MyUtils {
    . . .
    public static double mean(int[] p) {
        int sum = 0;  // sum of all the elements
        for (int i=0; i<p.length; i++) {
            sum += p[i];
        }
        return ((double)sum) / p.length;
    }
    . . .
}

// Called from outside the MyUtils class.
double meanAttendance = MyUtils.mean(attendance);
```

What's the equivalent 'Ruby way' of writing a 'static method'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anders' answer is correct, however for utility methods like `mean` you don't need to use a class, you can put the method in a [module](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html):

```
module MyUtils
  def self.mean(values)
    # implementation goes here
  end
end
```

The method would be called in the same way:

```
avg = MyUtils.mean([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Answer (score 10):

Use self:

```
class Horse
  def self.say
    puts "I said moo."
  end
end

Horse.say
```

Comment: It is a very special horse :)

Comment: @Nathan W: I thought that [Horse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Footrot_Flats#Main_characters) went miaow.